# How to write Sharepoint online extension to store meta data in markdown files?

Tags: typescript, markdown, metadata, sharepoint-online

Sharepoint stores meta data for some file formats (`*.docx`, `*.xlsx`, `*.html`, ...) directly in the files. Here is an example for `*.html` content, including a custom meta data property `MyMetaDataProperty`:

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:MyMetaDataProperty msdt:dt="string">MyMetaDataValue</mso:MyMetaDataProperty >
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head></html>
```

Also see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34164/how-is-metadata-stored

However, for `*.md` files, the meta data is not stored in the files but mangaged in an extra database.

**=> How can I write a [Sharepoint extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) changing this behavior?**

I would like to store the meta data columns for my `*.md` files directly in the `*.md` files, using a format that is compatible to **Obsidian** and **Quertz**:

https://quartz.jzhao.xyz/authoring-content#syntax

```
---
title: Example Title
draft: false
tags:
  - example-tag
---
 
The rest of your content lives here. You can use **Markdown** here :)
```

Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X765V2bQ2e8

**Related:**

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310586/how-to-remove-border-from-file-and-media-web-part

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310609/how-to-link-another-markdown-file-in-sharepoint-online

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/markdown-document-template-in-a-sharepoint-document-library/m-p/2205548